# Undefined local variable or method `configuration' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostGIS::PostGISDatabaseTasks:0x0000555b2c8f5ac0>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've just upgraded my rails version from 5.2 to 6.1 and built my docker image.

when i run `docker compose up` I'm encountering an error message related to the PostGISDatabaseTasks class. Specifically, I'm seeing an error message that reads

```
'undefined local variable or method 'configuration' for #ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostGIS::PostGISDatabaseTasks:0x0000555b2c8f5ac0. Did you mean? configuration_hash'.
```

GemFile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '~> 2.7'

gem 'pg', '~> 1.2', '>= 1.2.3'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.1.7' , '>= 6.1.7.1'
gem 'responders', '~> 3.0', '>= 3.0.1'

gem 'actionpack-action_caching', '~> 1.2', '>= 1.2.1'
gem 'activerecord-postgis-adapter', '~> 6.0', '>= 6.0.1'
gem 'addressfinder'
gem 'aws-sdk-s3'
gem 'aws-sdk-dynamodb'
gem 'bugsnag'
gem 'cancan'
gem 'clearance', '~> 2.5.0'
gem 'coffee-rails'
gem 'dynamic_form'
gem 'easy_reference_data', '~> 1.1'
gem 'ejs', '~> 1.0.0'
gem 'friendly_id'
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 4.4'
gem 'mapkit'
gem 'mime-types', require: 'mime/types'
gem 'newrelic_rpm'
gem 'nokogiri', '>= 1.13.2'
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'puma', '>= 5.6.2'
gem 'rails_12factor'
gem 'rgeo', '~> 2.2'
gem 'rgeo-geojson', '~> 2.1', '>= 2.1.1'
gem 'rinku', '~> 1.5.1', require: 'rails_rinku'
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
gem 'will_paginate'
gem "whenever", "~> 1.0"
gem "net-http"
gem 'uri', '0.12.0'

group :foreman do
  gem 'foreman'
end

group :test do
  gem 'database_cleaner', '~> 1.99.0'
  gem 'factory_bot_rails'
  gem 'guard-minitest'
  gem 'guard-rspec', require: false
  gem 'minitest'
  gem 'mocha', require: false
  gem 'shoulda'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'bundler-audit'
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'license_finder'
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'pry-nav'
  gem 'pry-remote'
  gem 'rails-controller-testing'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.8'
end
```

I'm not sure what is causing this error or how to resolve it.

Can anyone provide guidance on how to resolve this error ? Thank you for your help and i can provide more info if needed.

More Info:

```
wait-for-it.sh: postgresql:5432 is available after 0 seconds
undefined local variable or method `configuration' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostGIS::PostGISDatabaseTasks:0x0000555b2c8f5ac0>
Did you mean?  configuration_hash
Couldn't create 'app' database. Please check your configuration.
rake aborted!
NameError: undefined local variable or method `configuration' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostGIS::PostGISDatabaseTasks:0x0000555b2c8f5ac0>
Did you mean?  configuration_hash
/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-postgis-adapter-6.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgis/postgis_database_tasks.rb:99:in `ensure_installation_configs'
/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-postgis-adapter-6.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgis/postgis_database_tasks.rb:9:in `initialize'
/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7.2/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:487:in `new'
/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7.2/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:487:in `database_adapter_for'
/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7.2/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:133:in `create'
/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7.2/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:193:in `block in create_current'
/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7.2/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:506:in `block (2 levels) in each_current_configuration'
/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7.2/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:503:in `each'
/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7.2/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:503:in `block in each_current_configuration'
/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7.2/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:502:in `each'
/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7.2/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:502:in `each_current_configuration'
/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7.2/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:193:in `create_current'
/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.1.7.2/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:45:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bugsnag-6.24.2/lib/bugsnag/integrations/rake.rb:20:in `execute'
/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.4.6/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:58:in `load'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.4.6/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:58:in `kernel_load'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.4.6/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:23:in `run'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.4.6/lib/bundler/cli.rb:491:in `exec'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.4.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.4.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.4.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.4.6/lib/bundler/cli.rb:34:in `dispatch'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.4.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in `start'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.4.6/lib/bundler/cli.rb:28:in `start'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.4.6/exe/bundle:45:in `block in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.4.6/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:117:in `with_friendly_errors'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.4.6/exe/bundle:33:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bundle/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bundle/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Please add the complete stack trace.

Comment: you need to update the `activerecord-postgis-adapter`. Per the [Docs](https://github.com/rgeo/activerecord-postgis-adapter#version-7x-supports-activerecord-61) *"Version 6.x supports ActiveRecord 6.0"* and *"Version 7.x supports ActiveRecord 6.1"* given that you are using ActiveRecord 6.1 you will need to update to the Version 7 adapter.